# UICollectionView Selected Cell Index is always zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented UICollectionView like in this tutorial: [UICollectionView Tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial)

When I implement

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger i = indexPath.item;

return YES;
```

}

or

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger i = indexPath.item;

return YES;
```

}

always 
i = 0

I've tried adding an ID property to Photo Object and assigning it but without an index I can't do nothing.What to do here please help I'm stuck.

I am trying to get selected index and to view selected photo in a new view controller but couldn't get index of selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSIndexPath` that you get from those methods has `row` and `section` that you should use to get what you need

Comment: I don't know how I passed by it.I had tried `indexPath.row` but `indexPath.section` gives the index that i needed.I didn't try it even once.Thank you.